# Single quote character and wildcard in an SQLite query cases SQLiteException

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a search function in my app:

```
String selection = DatabaseContract.DbEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " like '%" + searchQuery + "%'";
```

When a **user searches for ' like I'm, the app crashes** raising an android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException.

**What I want** is the capability of the searching for that ' in the user input?

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any externally supplied values, use variables in SQL:

```
String selection = DatabaseContract.DbEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " like '%' || ? || '%'";
```

with `searchQuery` in `selectionArgs` as value to be bound.